# Total and average the numbers next to each of the same string

Tags: bash

```
hotel_99466.dat:5
hotel_99466.dat:4
hotel_99466.dat:5
hotel_99466.dat:3
hotel_99762.dat:5
hotel_99762.dat:4
hotel_99762.dat:2
hotel_99762.dat:5
```

I am looking to simplify this by averaging the numbers in accordance with the hotel number. And removing the '.dat:' so that this list can be simplified to:

```
hotel_99466 4.25
hotel_99762 4
```

This will need to go into a bash script. The data above is the output of a grep command so if anyone has any answers I can pipeline it in. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` should do it:

```
awk -F: '{
   c[$1]++
   s[$1]+=$2
}
END {
   for (i in c) { 
      avg = s[i] / c[i]
      sub(/\.dat$/, "", i)
      printf "%s %.2f\n", i, avg
   }
}' input_file
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
awk -F: '{c[$1]++;s[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in c){avg=s[i]/c[i];sub(/\.dat$/,"",i);printf "%s %.2f\n",i,avg}}' input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Install GNU datamash and use

```
yourCommand | datamash -t: -g 1 mean 2 | sed 's/\.dat:/ /'
```

Datamash will group by the first field and compute the average of the second field in each group. Datamash's output  will be

```
hotel_99466.dat:4.25
hotel_99762.dat:4
```

Sed will then post-process that output to replace `.dat:` with a space .

```
hotel_99466 4.25
hotel_99762 4
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is a University based server and I cannot install any other packages or commands on it - any other suggestions?